# How Can I Plot a Complex Function With Phase Information in MATLAB With Brightness

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, complex-numbers

I need to plot a complex function with phase information in MATLAB. To do this I have ploted a surf plot with x,y representing real and imaginary, the height representing the magnitude and colour depending on the phase, as shown below for the example of log(x):

```
xmin=-5;
xmax=5;
dx=0.1;
xReal = xmin:dx:xmax;
xImaginary = xmin:dx:xmax;
[x,y] = meshgrid(xReal, xImaginary);
s = x + 1i*y;
z=log(s);
magnitude = abs(z1);
Phase = angle(z);
figure;
h(1) = surf(x,y,magnitude,Phase,'EdgeColor','none');
xlabel('Real');
ylabel('imaginary');
legend('Magnitude');
```

This works, however features of the plot are very difficult to see. I'd desire instead to plot the height of the function as brightness. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you tried beta = 1;
brighten(h,beta) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the inverse of the `magnitude` value as the `AlphaData` which would cause higher values to be lighter (more transparent with a white axes behind it) and lower values to be darker (more opaque).

```
h = surf(x, y, zeros(size(magnitude)), 'EdgeColor', 'none');
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'flat', 'CData', Phase, 'FaceAlpha', 'flat', 'AlphaData', -magnitude);
view(2);
```

[image]

If you have other plot objects and can't rely on transparency, you can instead manually dither the colors with white.

```
% Determine the RGB color using the parula colormap
rgb = squeeze(ind2rgb(gray2ind(mat2gray(Phase(:))), parula));

% Normalize magnitude values
beta = magnitude(:) / max(magnitude(~isinf(magnitude)));

% Based on the magnitude, pick a value between the RGB color and white
colors = bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@times, (1 - beta), rgb), beta)

% Now create the surface
h = surf(x, y, zeros(size(magnitude)), 'EdgeColor', 'none');
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'flat', 'CData', reshape(colors, [size(magnitude), 3]));
```

That being said, I'm not sure if this makes it any easier to see what is happening. Maybe consider just making two plots, one for the magnitude and one for the phase.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the suggestion however unfortunately this work around wouldn't work in the situation I need it for (my fault, didn't think I would not to provide more than that minimal example), I'm plotting multiple functions in one plot so making it transparent wouldn't change the brightness it would just make it possible to see the other functions beneath.

Comment: @Jack Updated with a dithering-based approach.